# How to get the number of columns to the left border of the current window?

Tags: neovim, vim-windows

As title. I want to know the offset regardless of the current buffer. It's not the column number of the current buffer.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the following call gives you the value you are searching:

```
let col = win_screenpos(winnr())[1]
```

Comment: While this is not what I really want, this is the right answer to my title. (Sorry for my bad English grammar. I was trying to describe the columns between the cursor and the left border of the current window) Still many thanks for your kindness in trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out the answer is `wincol()`, or written in Lua `vim.fn.wincol()`.